# Is This Join Possible?

Tags: mysql, database, join, mysql-5.6

I have a couple of tables that look like this.

```
table_a     |   table_b
-------------------------
prim_key    |   prim_key
zero_or_one |   value1
valueA      |   value2
valueB      |   value3
valueZ      |
```

What I'm hoping to do is retrieve all of the values (`prim_key`, `value1`, `value2`, `value3`) from `TABLE B` if the primary keys of each table match and the value of `zero_or_one` in `TABLE A` is `0`.

I'm completely new to `joins`, and I'm not exactly sure which join I should be using for this, but it seems like a `FULL OUTER JOIN` is most appropriate.

```
SELECT table_b.*
FROM table_a
FULL OUTER JOIN table_b
ON table_a.prim_key = table_b.prim_key
```

Is this even possible?

Am I using the right join for the job?

Is my "select all" syntax correct?

Comment: MySQL does not have `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya r u serious?!?!

Comment: yes he is serious, you can simulate FULL OUTER JOIN in MYSQL like i answerd.

Comment: Well I havent been smoking anything today yet ! ;)

Comment: I think some sample data (especially covering edge cases) with expected output would be helpful.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya hahahah. edge case in what sense? there won't be any edge cases? this is literally the only query and type of output that i'm looking for

Comment: @Anthony -> "Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want entries from `table_b` only when there is a matching primary key found in the `table_a`; a simple `Inner Join` would suffice in this case

```
SELECT table_b.*
FROM table_b
INNER JOIN table_a
  ON table_a.prim_key = table_b.prim_key AND 
     table_a.zero_or_one = 0
```

Comment: you've misinterpreted my question. there are two conditions: (1) the `prim_key` in both tables must match one another, and (2) `zero_or_one` in `TABLE A` must have a value of `0`

Comment: @Anthony I am doing exactly the same here. Unless these two conditions are `OR` instead of `AND` ?

Comment: nono, the two conditions are `AND` conditions. since `table_a` will also contain additional columns of data, using an `inner join` doesn't also search/scan a bunch of data that we don't need to scan? i'll modify my question so that you can see what i mean.

Comment: @Anthony he is right this is the query needed.. "doesn't also search/scan a bunch of data that we don't need to scan?" You need to have indexes.  `table_a(prim_key, zero_or_one)` and `table_b(prim_key)` then the query will perform great.

Comment: @RaymondNijland ok, duly noted. this is beside the point, but i'm still slightly confused by descriptions of each joins. inner joins are described in one place as doing, ["The INNER JOIN keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables."](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) And then, ["This is the simplest, most understood Join and is the most common. This query will return all of the records in the left table (table A) that have a matching record in the right table (table B)."](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: @Anthony Please go through: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

Full table scanning depends on whether there is indexing done or not. Join solves a different problem; Indexing optimizes the Join.

Comment: if you don't have indexes @Anthony  then MySQL uses a nested block algoritm  to search the matches the algoritm is more or less `for(...) { for (...) {  if(row[value] != where[filter]) { continue; } send_record_to_client()  } }` for two tables .. the nested loops becomes more the more tables you have.

Comment: @RaymondNijland have you had a chance to contribute to the MySQL source code ? You seem to know quite a bit about the source code algo +1

Comment: @RaymondNijland ok, but did you notice how both of those descriptions of inner joins that i linked you to in my last comment are "misnomers". the first description says that "inner joins select records that have matching values in both tables", which, in addition to those diagrams that are found everywhere, makes it seem to the uninitiated as if the only records you can select are the records with identical values in both tables. the second description states you can only select records from table a...

Comment: @Anthony Links you shared are not official resources. One of them is w3resources which is quite notorious for providing wrong information. There was once a w3fools site too pointing out their mistakes. Please go through MySQL documentation for any clarification. Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not meant als a real answer this is meant how to simulate FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL.

FULL OUTER JOIN is not supported in MySQL you can simulate it with a LEFT JOIN, UNION ALL and RIGHT JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM table_a LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.prim_key = table_b.prim_key
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table_a RIGHT JOIN table_b ON table_a.prim_key = table_b.prim_key
WHERE table_a.prim_key IS NULL
```

Comment: is a `full outer join` (or a simulation thereof) the type of join that i should be using for this? my concern with your solution (and the hypothetical solution in my question) is that it might add unnecessary complexity and thus reduce performance.

Comment: @Anthony  mine answer was more a answer on how to simulate FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL it's not really a answer to your problem i geuss..

Comment: ok. so my last one question remains. (P.S. i've updated the table in my question to better reflect the actuality.) since a `full outer join` doesn't exist (if it was even the most appropriate join to be using in the first place), what is the most appropriate join for my needs?